# Title page link is invisible and appears in header for all frames beamer!

Tags: beamer

A link to the title page is invisible and appears in all frames in the header. Could someone please tell me how to remove it? [image]

The dotted line box. It appears on all pages and is very annoying.

This the main file:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usetheme{Simple}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The title
\title[Disentanglement]{Disentanglement for physical systems}
% \subtitle{Subtitle}

\author[Saied] {Youssef Saied}
\institute[EPFL] % Your institution may be shorthand to save space
{
    % Your institution for the title page
    Swiss Data Science Center \\
    École Polytechnique Fédérale de Lausanne 
    \vskip 3pt
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRESENTATION SLIDES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    % Print the title page as the first slide
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Style file:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Settings
\usetheme{Szeged}
\useinnertheme{circles}
% \useoutertheme{simpleinfo}
% \useoutertheme{miniframes} % Alternatively: miniframes, infolines, split
\usefonttheme{Simple}
\usecolortheme{whale}

% \setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
% table of contents (overview)
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[default]

\mode<all>

\mode<presentation>

%%%%%%%%%%%% fonts

\setbeamerfont{structure}{family=\sffamily,series=\mdseries}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\LARGE,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\normalsize,parent=title}

\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\scriptsize,series=\mdseries,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\Large,series=\mdseries,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\scriptsize,series=\mdseries,parent=structure}

\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\Large,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\tiny,parent=structure}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\large,parent={section in toc}}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{parent=structure,size=\LARGE}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{parent=frametitle,size=\Large}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{item}{parent=structure,series=\mdseries}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,series=\mdseries,parent={structure,block body}}

\mode
<all>



\definecolor{InvisibleRed}{rgb}{0.92, 0.9, 0.9}
\definecolor{InvisibleGreen}{rgb}{0.9, 0.92, 0.9}
\definecolor{InvisibleBlue}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.92}

\definecolor{LightBlue}{rgb}{0.4, 0.55, 0.65}

\definecolor{MediumRed}{rgb}{0.92549, 0.34509, 0.34509}
\definecolor{MediumGreen}{rgb}{0.36862, 0.66666, 0.65882}
\definecolor{MediumBlue}{rgb}{0.01176, 0.31372, 0.43529}

\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0.05, 0.15, 0.3} 

\usecolortheme[named=DarkBlue]{structure}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=DarkBlue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=MediumBlue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=LightBlue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=MediumBlue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=InvisibleBlue}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=MediumGreen}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=InvisibleGreen}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=MediumRed}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=InvisibleRed}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Without you providing a complete code example that reproduces the problem it is close to impossible to help.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I am editing the question now!

Answer (score 1):

The link belongs to the title at the top of the note pages. Because you are using the `show notes on second screen` option, the `pdfpages` package is used to position the notes next to the slides, but it can't reposition the link areas, see e.g. [Help for hyperlinks with pgfpages needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615312/help-for-hyperlinks-with-pgfpages-needed)

You have a couple of options to workaround this problem:

- if you don't need link on the main slides, you can position the notes on the left hand side
- switch off link in the notes as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\hypersetup{hidelinks}}{}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```