# Help for hyperlinks with pgfpages needed

Tags: pgfpages

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{0.5pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=0.92\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.92\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
\begin{document}
\href{https://twitter.com/foodyrelish}{Go to Twitter}\\
\textcolor[rgb]{0.5,0,0.5}{\colorbox[rgb]{0.75,0.75,0.75}{\texttt{Internal Links}}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{Link for Facebook: \url{https://twitter.com/foodyrelish}}
\item{Link for Twitter: \url{https://www.facebook.com/Foody-Relish-105377898514997}}
\item{Link for Instagram: \url{https://www.instagram.com/foodyrelish12/}}
\item{Link for Linkedin: \url{https://www.linkedin.com/in/vishakha-potdar-2205031aa/}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry but it won't work. If you shrink the page like this with pgfpages the links are misplaced. If you only want a border around the page you don't need pgfpages, you can draw it e.g. with eso-pic or the shipout hooks.

Answer (score 2):

The pgf manual explicitly warns about this

> A word of warning: using pgfpages *will destroy hyperlinks*. Actually, the hyperlinks are not destroyed,
> only they will appear at totally wrong positions on the final output.

If you don't use colorlinks but links borders you can see the problem e.g. in adobe reader. All link rectangle are misplaced. It is therefore not recommended to use pgfpages if links are involved. Borders around pages can be easily implemented without it.

[image]

Comment: Okay , Thanks! So will u tell me how I can make borders

Comment: that is a new question, so ask a new question. But search first e.g. for eso-pic.