hyperref not aligning with text when page is bordered in a box
I need pages of my document to be bordered and I want to use hyperref for cross-section references to my equations, graphs and tables. But when I use them together, the reference is not aligned with hypertext (the red box doesn't lay on the text).
How should I fix this?
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
%\expandafter\let\csname ver@xpatch.sty\endcsname\empty
\ExpandArgs{c}\def{ver@xpatch.sty}{3000/12/12}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase = \text{--}}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
    \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
    {%
        logical pages=1,%
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {       
        border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
        %       border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    \rho_\text{v}=R_\text{v}\frac{S_\text{ef}}{h}=R_\text{v}\frac{\pi(d_\text{m}+Bc)^2}{4h},
\end{equation}

Reference to equation \eqref{eq:1}.
\end{document}



do not use pgfpages in this case. Borders can be made with eso-pic or shipout hooks. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615328/2388
